# How to check if local time is equal to between a "startdate" and "enddate" Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to check for a condition to see if my current local time is equal to either to "startdate" or the "enddate" provided by the server. here is the request made to get the data:

js:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/getdata",
     type: "GET",
     success: function(res) {
       console.log(res);
    }
 });
```

here is what i get in the "res" : the timings are in the epoch format.

```
{
   "result" : "OK",
   "data" : {
     "offset" : 0,
      "items" : [ {
        "message" : "notice hgfwug",
        "endDate" : 1451992260000,
        "startDate" : 1451819460000,
        "subject" : "test notice423423",
        "id" : 897
       } ],
     "total" : 1,
     "more" : false
    }
 }
```

Now i want to check if my local date is equal to the date between the start date and the end date. Also since the dates are in epoch format, im sure how to check them against the local time.
something like below:

```
if(res.data.items[0].startDate && res.data.items[0].endDate == new Date()){
 alert("time matched");
}else{
  // dont do anything
 }
```

Ideas much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get the current local time as a unix timestamp in `ms` via

```
var now = Date.now();
```

If you want to check if the current local time is **equal** to either the start or end dates, try

```
if (now === res.data.items[0].startDate || now === res.data.items[0].endDate) {
    // ... 
}
```

That's pretty unlikely though given the level of precision (milliseconds).

If on the other hand you want to check if the current local time is **between** the start and end dates (inclusive), then try

```
if (now >= res.data.items[0].startDate && now <= res.data.items[0].endDate) {
    // ...
}
```